# Referencing Table & Referenced Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm trying to understand relationships and naturally questions appear.

[image: MySQL Workbench screenshot]

What does referencing table mean and what does referenced table mean? In the above example which one should be referenced and which one referencing?
Lets say for the sake of argument that the `settlements` table is a child table (settlement cannot exist without a country). Should this child table be referencing or referenced?

I prefer not to open a new question for such a little question:
What does that `Mandatory` checkbox mean? Does it mean that the settlements table is required or that `country_id` is required? Or maybe something else?

Comment: maybe I should post this in the english.stackexchange.com :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Found a really good explanation in the PostgreSQL documentation.

Say you have the product table that we have used several times already:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product_no integer PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    price numeric
);
```

Let's also assume you have a table storing orders of those products. We want to ensure that the orders table only contains orders of products that actually exist. So we define a foreign key constraint in the orders table that references the products table:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id integer PRIMARY KEY,
    product_no integer REFERENCES products (product_no),
    quantity integer
);
```

Now it is impossible to create orders with product_no entries that do not appear in the products table.

**We say that in this situation the orders table is the *referencing* table and the products table is the *referenced* table. Similarly, there are referencing and referenced columns.**

Comment: For ones who are peculiar about naming convention, it's better to name table in singular manner `product` and `order`.

Answer (score 8):

The referenced table is the 'parent' table.

The referencing table is the 'child' table.

The clue is in the SQL DDL e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE Settlements ADD
   FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
   REFERENCES Countries (id);
```

Settlements references Countries, implies Countries is referenced.

Answer (score 2):

**`settlements` table** (with the country_id field) **is referencing** to **`countries` table** (the id field)

I suppose mandatory checkbox has nothing to do with the relation. It is simply a not null constraint on the field. But you should consult the user manual of MySQL Workbench on this one.

Comment: So this diagram I made is correct? settlemets should be the referencing table?

Comment: yupp, and `countries` should be the referenced one

Comment: I don't think so. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Mandatory check box, if it seems to have no effect in generated SQL, has some effect on the graphic. If unchecked, you can see little circle at concerned relation line extremity (for Relationship notation crow's foot).

It means that the foreign key could be null, aka. not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

One country can have many settlements so the country table is the referenced table and the settlement table is the referencing table. I don't know about mandatory field.

Comment: the `settlements` table contains the `country_id` field which references the `countries` table. So, I conclude, the `settlements` table is referencing the `countries` table.

Comment: True, but a country can have many settlements. IMO is the country table the parent table. It's impossible to navigate through settlements to find the country.

Comment: @Betterdev What you mean is the difference between one-to-many and many-to-one relationships.

Comment: @what: IMO I made it clear in my comment (parent table).